# Joining multiple values from a List<string>

Tags: c#, list

Im currently working on this little project, and found myself in a difficult way to do this:
As shown in the picture, in my quickwatch there are 4 values.

[image]

values of which `0` goes with `2` and `1` goes with `3`, and so forth (this can be unlimited)

So far, I have made the code work just by putting it into a `foreach`, but it's not joining `0` with `2` and `1` with `3` and so forth. (depending on the maximum count inside the List)

> Desired result:  (reffering to quickwatch)
>
> usb_device contains:
>
> [0] and [2] together resulting: Drive F... Vid: 0781`
>
> [,1] and [3] together resulting: Drive D... Vid: 125F`

`Actual result: (see quickwatch), everything is stacked underneath but
 not yet joined as such by the desired result.`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! A few points of note. Images should be reserved for cases where they are strictly necessary such as GUI issues. Code, data, and errors should be provided in the text of your question. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Please provide some code and maybe expected output vs actual output to help us answer your question.

Comment: Are you sure about 0-2 and 1-3 pairs? I would say that for 6 entries you will have 0-3, 1-4  and 2-5.

Comment: Are you able to edit your post to show "Expected Outcome" vs "Actual Outcome"?

Comment: It's likely you're using a WMI query to get this info - can you also post that query? The answer might be to refine the query rather than try and perform magic on your `List<string>` of results.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the string array "Drive F:..." to go with "VID: 0781..."?

Comment: @GuruStron, yes, this is true. the wmi code actually populates the drives first,(and size) and then goes into finding pid/vid, which gives the desired result, but the actual result is what you're suggesting.

Comment: @JoshMaag Yes, you are correct. this is the desired output, and the actual output is shown as in the quickwatch, the desired output should be those values joined together so in this instance we would have [2] objects in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll actually want to change your loop to be a for loop instead of a for each loop. Let's make the assumption that Usb.FindDevices.Get() always returns an even number, and is always in the correct order. Because if not, then you'll need an entirely different solution where you find the relationship between them and handle edge cases like an odd number of entries.

If that's the case, then we need to calculate the total number of devices, I'm assuming it's half the number of entries, so we would do this:

```
int totalDeviceCount = usb_devices.Count / 2;
```

Then you would want to loop through our "devices" which are the first half of the list and append the second half of the list at the same time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < totalDeviceCount; i++) {
{
    SystemLog.AppendText(String.Format("{0} - {1}", usb_devices[i], usbdevices[i + totalDeviceCount]));
}
```

What this will do on your example input is put take the first [0] and third [2] and put them together by adding the total number of devices (2) to the current `i` variable, then on the 2nd iteration through the loop it will grab [1] and [3]. At the next iteration `i` will equal 2 and will no longer be less than the total number of devices so it will exit the loop.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're 100% correct, this is exactly what i wanted! (u forgot string.format inside of the appendtext and forgot to put usb_devices in the 2nd parameter {1}) but yeah after those changes, this is exactly what i wanted. and 100% accurate!

i'll try to do my best and post my future issues more in-depth, although it's a littlebit hard i will try.~ thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var col = new List<string>() { "0", "1", "2", "3" };

var pairs = col.Take(col.Count / 2)
               .Select((s, i) => (s, col[i + col.Count / 2] ))
               .ToList();
```